# Why pthread_Join is not working when using RR or FIFO scheduler LINUX UBUNTU

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

So I've modified the IBM example code for pthread_attr_setdetachstate to better understand how to use it, I've noticed that if I set the thread policy to SCHED_RR or SCHED_FIFO then the main function doesn't wait for the thread to finish and just exits.

however if I set the policy to SCHED_OTHER it waits for the thread to finish.

why is this happening?

```
/* CELEBP11 */
#define _OPEN_THREADS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void **stat;
void *thread1(void *arg)
{
   printf("hello from the thread\n");
   pthread_exit((void *)0);
}

int main()
{
   int            ds, rc;
   size_t         s1;
   pthread_attr_t attr;
   pthread_t      thid;

   rc = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   if (rc == -1) {
      perror("error in pthread_attr_init");
      exit(1);
   }
   rc = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
   if (rc == -1) {
      perror("error in pthread_attr_setdetachstate");
      exit(2);
   }

   rc = pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr,PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
   if (rc == -1) {
      perror("error in pthread_attr_setdetachstate");
      exit(4);
   }


   rc = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy (&attr, SCHED_RR);
   if (rc != 0) {
      perror("error in pthread_attr_setschedpolicy");
      exit(5);
   }

   struct sched_param param_test;

   param_test.sched_priority = 50;

   rc = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param_test);
   if (rc == -1) {
      perror("error in pthread_attr_setschedparam");
      exit(6);
   }

   rc = pthread_create(&thid, &attr, thread1, NULL);
   if (rc == -1) {
      perror("error in pthread_create");
      exit(3);
   }


   rc = pthread_join(thid, stat);
   exit(0);
}
```

to compile

```
gcc test.c -lpthread -lrt   -o test2
```

Comment: BTW the `pthread_join(..., stat)` is a **very** ugly way of writing `, NULL);`.

Comment: I didn't modify that, its how the IBM documentation wrote it

Comment: Furthermore, `stat` is a system call name, and this identifier now clashes with it, bad bad IBM.

Comment: If you use `strace` you will see that the `sched_setscheduler` system call will error and the thread is killed with a realtime signal, and the thread is *cancelled* (if used with a non-null pointer, the `pthread_join` would give `PTHREAD_CANCELLED`. I do not know exactly why this happens, so I've not written an answer yet.

Comment: when I try to run the program as root then it works, perhaps its a permission issue then

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971910/how-to-get-permission-for-pthread-setschedparam

Comment: man pthread_create: *RETURN VALUE
       On success, pthread_create() returns 0; on error, it returns an error number,
       and the contents of *thread are undefined.*

Comment: @eof good point. If that is the reason it is worth an answer since this is IBM code :P

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Given the number of issues with this code, either the OP messed it up worse than they think, or IBM had a bad intern write it. Not sure what benefit an answer would provide, other than "don't use this example".

Comment: OP: If you can provide a link to the *original* code and it presents the same problems then it can be worth answering...

Comment: this is the original https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.bpxbd00/ptasetd.htm as I said I modified the code, I added giving it a priority, scheduler such as FIFO or RR and setinheritsched.